# The {layout} tag is redundant

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At first sight, [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) seems like a useful general concept which fully deserves the 61 questions tagged with it at the moment.

On closer examination, these questions can be divided into three major and a lot of minor (tag) areas. The major concepts are:

- Customizing page margins -- [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins), [geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [typearea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typearea), ...
- Customizing headers and footers -- [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer), [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style), [fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr), [scrpage2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrpage2), ...
- Using multiple columns -- [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column), [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns), [multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicol), ...

Some minor concepts associated with [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) are [marginpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marginpar), [positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positioning), [page-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-breaking), [landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscape), ... Also, [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats) are sometimes categorized as [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout).

In my opinion, "broad" concept tags are useful if there are either questions that don't fit into a specific concept or package (this is the case for e.g. [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams)) or if solutions given for a specific area are likely to be applicable more generally (this is why questions about specific list environments should also be tagged with [lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists)). For [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout), neither is the case. Every question tagged this way will need additional, more specific tags, and the answers of one [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) subarea will be of little or no help in another subarea.

I propose that, after skimming through the [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) questions and adding specific tags where appropriate, the [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) tag should be abolished.

EDIT: "Killing" a tag (i.e., removing it from every question) can be done automatically and without flooding the start page -- Jeff Atwood did it with the [picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture) tag.

Comment: +1. Did you look through the {layout} questions to see whether there are questions that are only tagged {layout} (or {layout} + something non-descriptive)?

Comment: @Caramdir: There are about half a dozen questions that feature either only {layout} or {layout} plus {lyx}. There also may be questions with a mismatch between tags and actual content.

Comment: An additional justification for tags is that they can make it easier for people to follow questions on topics that interest them: e.g., [tikz-pgf] has 71 followers, [lyx] has 24.  [layout] has only four followers, so that doesn't really seem to apply here.  That said, I don't know good a proxy number of followers is for the use of tags by people who follow a topic in this way: there is the RSS feed, and I often use them manually.

Comment: @lockstep: You probably know, but let me point out that LyX layouts have nothing to do with what you're describing in the question. (I actually have no idea what a LyX layout actually _is_.)

Comment: @Hendrik: So we should introduce {lyx-layouts}?

Comment: @Caramdir: I think so, yes, but as I said, I have no idea about the subject that tag would cover, so I'm a bad judge here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a week has passed and my proposal has gained some upvotes and positive comments, I will start to skim through questions tagged with [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout). I will only retag questions manually where other tags need to be added, changed, or deleted; when this is done, the [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) tag may be "killed" automatically.

EDIT: I completed the manual retagging. The [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) tag may now be "killed" by a moderator, i.e. removed from the 21 questions still featuring it.

Comment: I created {lyx-layout} and added it to the appropriate questions.

Comment: That should have been {lyx-layouts}. Let me retag again...

Comment: This reminds me that the {style} tag  is almost as useless as {layout} ...

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: In accordance with the above retagging proposal, please remove the {layout} tag from every question featuring it.

Comment: ok, this is done!

Comment: @Jeff: Many thanks!